# Is it possible to indicate several destination directories to Javac?

Tags: java, javac, serialversionuid

I wrote a Java class, let A, which must be compiled once and saved in several directories (let Y, and Z). Therefore, the compiled files would have the same *SerialVersionUID* (I need it), in any directory (Y and Z).

I tried to make use of `javac A.java -d Y -d Z` but it doesn't work.

By the way, I can't make a first compilation and then a copy (i.e. : `javac A.java -d Y; cp Y/A.class Z`), because the *SerialVersionUID* will be different...

How could I solve this problem ?

EDIT : an ultimate solution would be to set the *SerialVersionUID* definitively in the .java files, but I would want to avoid it.

Comment: Specify the serial version uid explicitly. Then copy from the first to second directory. Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: In the `javac` command ? Or in the .java files ?

Comment: No, in the source code.

Comment: Well if it's the only one solution ok =/ I find it quite dirty in fact

Comment: The serialVersionUid of a class doesn't depend on where the .class file is stored on your disk. Your question doesn't make much sense, because it's based on incorrect assumptions. It's also unclear 1. why you deal with .class files and not jar files, 2. why you need a .class file in two separate directories.

Comment: Note: if you need to care about the value of serial version uid, you should specify it explicitly anyway. Otherwise you could compile the same class on two compilers and get different values.

Comment: "However, it is strongly recommendedthat all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value." From java.io.Serializable.

Comment: Copying a class file does not change its `serialVersionUID`, nor does recompiling it (assuming the source is the same).

Comment: Well thank you guys, I wrote a precise sVUID, but the problem seems to be elsewhere (I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612408/despite-recompilation-still-the-error-local-class-incompatible-stream-classd )